# GraphQL Viewer for mutations

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Is it a good practice to have a viewer for GraphQL mutations? Theoretically this makes sense to me as some mutation end points shouldn't be possible if you are not logged in, etc.

But when I see examples on the web, I only see implementation of GraphQL viewers for queries. For mutations, I do not see any implementation of viewers. For example, the GitHub API doesn't have a viewer on top of all their mutations.

Answer (score 8):

The `viewer` field isn't a good practice, either for mutations or queries. It's a remnant of Facebook's legacy GraphQL platform from before it was open-sourced, which didn't allow arguments on root query fields. This meant that all of the fields needed to be moved one level down, below `viewer`.

The current way to do auth in GraphQL, at least in the JavaScript implementation, is by getting the user data based on something like an HTTP header and putting it on `context`, as mentioned here: http://graphql.org/learn/authorization/

Therefore, there is no reason to do viewer for mutations, or for queries. Most GraphQL clients don't mind, but one situation where it could make sense to have it in queries specifically is if you are using Relay 0.x, which has inherited some of Facebook's legacy GraphQL limitations. Hopefully a future version of Relay will remove this requirement.

For an additional source, read [this comment](https://github.com/lucasbento/graphql-pokemon/issues/1#issue-184547046) from Lee Byron, one of the original creators of GraphQL.

Comment: I'll not agree that using `viewer` is bad practice. A lot of data in many modern apps is closely tied with context of who is viewing this data. Eg. my facebook friends are different than yours. In such case it's handy to have root viewer field that will limit the scope of sub queries properly. Things like search etc is also quite often tied with context of who is searching. Could you provide some resource where Relay is saying that concept of viewer is there only because of legacy reasons?

Comment: In more recent GraphQL releases there's a concept of "context" which is an underlying thing that lets you get information about the current user. Therefore, it's unnecessary to have that be a field in the actual schema.

Comment: Here's a comment from Lee Byron, the creator of GraphQL, about it: https://github.com/lucasbento/graphql-pokemon/issues/1#issue-184547046